# Where body is put in post with http request plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This might be the silliest question, but definitely it is not obvious.
I am trying to send a POST request in Jenkins, using the HTTP Request Plugin. However I cannot find a field to put the body message/content, that I want to post.
Any ideas?
This is a screenshot of the available options
[image: http request plugin]

Answer (score 2):

You can submit the body content using **requestBody**

```
httpRequest authentication: "credentialsID", contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON", httpMode: "POST", requestBody: JsonOutput.toJson(VALUE), url: dest_url
```

More Info: [HTTP Request Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no support to send body content.

There is a pull request under approval and it might be merged soon.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin/pull/14