# how to sent file(zip) using httprequest plugin jenkins

Tags: jenkins, httprequest, jenkins-pipeline, appdynamics, dsym

I have a requirement to upload zip file to appDynamics, i need to use the httpsrequest plugin for that from my jenkins pipeline

**upload request for appdynamics**:

```
curl -v -H Content-Type:application/octet-stream --upload-file UISampleApp.app.dSYM.zip --user Example account:Example-License-Key-4e8ec2ae6cfe https://api.eum-appdynamics.com/v2/account/Example+account/ios-dsym
```

we are using a shell to execute the above request now but I am trying to find out how to sent multiple zip files using [httpsRequest plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945370/how-to-post-json-data-in-body-with-jenkins-http-request-plugin-and-pipeline

Answer (score 3):

Following Code worked for me :

```
def response =  httpRequest(acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_ZIP',
                   customHeaders  : [[name: "authorization" , value : "${authToken}"],[name: 'x-username' , value: 'admin']],
                   httpMode: 'POST', ignoreSslErrors: true, 
                   multipartName: '<fileName>', timeout: 900,
                   responseHandle: 'NONE', uploadFile: "<filePath>", 
                   url: "${url}")
```

Comment: which version of plugin you are using

Comment: @deepak what if you want to upload the file to specific key in the request?

Comment: Above answer inspired me to get this working with httpRequest plugin. I had to use `POST` in combination with the following parameters `ContentType: 'APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM`, `uploadFile: 'file.zip'`, `multipartName: 'file.zip'`, `wrapAsMultipart: false` to get it working for uploading files to Azure Devops (as attachments).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like httprequest plugin does not support uploading zip file. This is my observation.

Answer (score 0):

I think upload will use `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. But httpRequest plugin is not supporting this type. However it supports `APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM(ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)`

Could you post output from your curl?